# How Can I Use Regex To Split A String on Letters and Numbers and Carets followed by digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

So I was wondering how I would go about splitting a String on specific characters/conditions using Regular Expressions like the following:

- On digits
- On Letters
- On digits following a caret

Here could be an example:

```
var str1 = "62y^2";
```

Would return as an array:

```
[62,y,^2]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `{62,y,^2}` isn't an array.

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve] , input and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of split with the following regular expression ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UBNbnS/1)):

```js
var str="62y^2ad23^123";

var result = str.match(/\^?\d+|[a-z]+/gi);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following approach:

```js
var str="62y^2ad23^123";

console.log(str.split(/(\^\d+|[a-zA-Z]+|\d+)/).filter(function(n){ return n != "" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex

```
var str = "62y^2";
str.match(/\^(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)|[a-zA-Z]+|\d+/g); // ["62", "y", "^2"]
```